# What is the meaning of "$" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE $.``.age > 20
```

I have tried the following

Valid queries:

- ```
  select * from table1 where $.``.age > 20
  ```
- ```
  select * from table1 where ``.age > 20
  ```
- ```
  select * from table1 where `table1.age` > 20
  ```
- ```
  select * from table1 where $$.``.age > 20`
  ```

Invalid queries

```
       select * from table1 where $.\`table1\`.age > 20
```

Answer (score 1):

`$` is [valid in unquoted identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) but doesn't have any special meaning as far as I know. You could replicate your question with any other text:

```
mysql> select *
    -> from information_schema.engines
    -> where typewhateverhere.``.transactions='YES';
+--------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| ENGINE | SUPPORT | COMMENT                                                    | TRANSACTIONS | XA   | SAVEPOINTS |
+--------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| InnoDB | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys | YES          | YES  | YES        |
+--------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't have the faintest idea of what does syntax mean for MySQL, though, it doesn't seem documented among [Identifier Qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

Comment: Interestingly, if you try `use $.\`\`` or `use \`\``, then you get error messages.

Comment: The format is 'db_name.tbl_name.col_name', so it seems to me instead of returning error, MySQL simply ignore the db_name in where clause, that's why you can use any valid unquoted identifiers, you can use '$', '$$', or '$no$such$db' cause it will be ignored anyway.